# Setting dialog width in Android 4

Tags: android, dialog, width, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a number of dialogs in a application where a custom view is used. Prior to Android 4 the height and width of these dialogs are adapting as I would expect according to the content. In an Andorid 4 emulator this behavior has changed. It looks like the width will stretch to accomodate content but it has a minimum size below which it will not go. I can make a dialog wider but for narrow content the dialog box will not reduce as I would expect. My content is therefore showing in the left side of an overwide dialog box. All works perfectly on 3.0. I have tried:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.help_dialog);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

This has no effect. Also the content of the title is not forcing the dialog to extend. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also have same issues ? , any answers ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - fixed it with it:

```
final Dialog help = new Dialog(this);
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(help.getWindow().getAttributes());

lp.width = (int) (width);
lp.height = (int) (height);

help.show();
help.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can set the margin and padding of the dialog in a drawable xml

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(r.drawable.your_drawable);
    dialog.getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_dialog_layout);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    dialog.show();
```

take a look at the r.drawable.your_drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list>
    <item
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:left="70dp"
        android:right="70dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="70dip"
                android:left="70dip"
                android:right="70dip"
                android:top="70dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

By setting the item android:right/left it margins the drawable.
With the shape padding you make sure fields wihtin the custom_dialog_layout do not exceed the width of the dialog background.

I hope it helps you a little bit.